# doxygen separate interface(.h)/implemetation(.c) documentation

Tags: doxygen

I'm trying to generate a doxygen document where I have two documentation instances for functions. One describes the usage(interface) of the functions that get pulled from the function header in the .h file and the other describes implementation of the function that gets pulled from the .c file. I basically want to describe the same function in two different ways based on where the file that the description came from(.h or .c). I thought this would help the usability of the document since you can easily ignore the implementation details if you only care about how to use the functions. My best attempt was to try to add the .h and the .c files to separate groups like this.

example.h

```
/**
 * @defgroup exampleInterface Example Interface
 * @{
 */

/**
 * This is the header file so I describe how to use this function
 * @param arg
 * @returns something
 */   
 int someFunction(int arg);

/**
* @}
*/
```

example .c

```
/**
 * @defgroup exampleImpl Example Implementation
 * @{
 */

/**
 * This is the .c file so I describe how this function is implemented.
 */   
 int someFunction(int arg)
 {
    ... Some code ...
 }
/**
 * @}
 */
```

The result was that the function header descriptions were still combined. Is there anyway to accomplish this in doxygen? Maybe there is another way I should look at this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A possible hack you could try is to use the @internal command for the implementation which would mean you would run doxygen twice: once without the internal (for the external definitions) and the other with the inernal which would combine them.